# Dynamics 365 custom javascript won't execute save after setting field level notification

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

I set a field level notification when the data in the field is not valid. Then I change the data to something that is valid but because I have set the notification onSave will not be fired.

```
function ValidateFields(executionContext) {

console.log("Init");

var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

var bfenummer_value =  formContext.getAttribute("kk_ejerlav").getValue();
var bfenummer_control = formContext.getControl("kk_ejerlav");
var bfenummer_uniqueid = "bfenummer";

if(!isNumeric(bfenummer_value))
{
    bfenummer_control.setNotification("Angiv et tal mellem -2147483648 og 2147483647", bfenummer_uniqueid);
    console.log("Set " + isNumeric(bfenummer_value));

    // setTimeout(function () {
    //     bfenummer_control.clearNotification(bfenummer_uniqueid);            
    //     console.log("Clear " + isNumeric(bfenummer_value));
    // }, 1000);
}
else {
    bfenummer_control.clearNotification(bfenummer_uniqueid);            
    console.log("Clear " + isNumeric(bfenummer_value));
}

}

function isNumeric(value) {
  return /^-?\d+$/.test(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a function on OnChange event for the "kk_ejerlav" field.
Something like this:

```
function ejerlavChanged(executionContext){
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

    var bfenummer_value =  formContext.getAttribute("kk_ejerlav").getValue();
    var bfenummer_control = formContext.getControl("kk_ejerlav");
    var bfenummer_uniqueid = "bfenummer";

    if(isNumeric(bfenummer_value)){
        bfenummer_control.clearNotification(bfenummer_uniqueid);            
        console.log("Clear " + isNumeric(bfenummer_value));
    }
}

function isNumeric(value) {
  return /^-?\d+$/.test(value);
}
```